# Searching a ticketing system, recommendations

Tags: linux, ldap, ticket-system

I'm searching a ticketing system in order to implement it on some business. I need a ticketing system with these possibilities and characteristics (if it's possible) or the maximum of it:

- Must be compatible with Linux
- Open-source code and free software
- Compatible with LDAP (I want to do authentications with LDAP)
- Possibility to open a ticket and receive the answer via mail (user's side, operators can have the web interface, they should but not must)
- The system should contain a wiki section or something like that in order to implement some guides & FAQs for users

I know that I'm searching for a very specific ticketing system and I'm being very demanding :P but I should do in that way.

If you know some ticketing system that provides several of these options your answers will be also welcome.

Thanks for all!

Comment: Voting to close : "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool, software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.". Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs. Tnx

Comment: See https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com where such a question my be on topic, but please be sure to check the help section there also. Good luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The characteristics you want are very similar with the ticket system I do use in my company.

I suggest to you the [GLPi](http://glpi-project.org/spip.php?lang=en) ticket system, is open source and fill all your requirements.

I hope you like it :D

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I'll have a look and I'll tell you something. Thank you!

(If you or community know more options just post them!)

Comment: @msabate i have a lot of options more, but with LDAP, for linux, open source, possibility for tickets via email and FAQ or wiki support. GLPi is the best option i have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at **Redmine**, it should have everything you want. You can use LDAP as user management, implement a wiki per projet, be notified by mail when a ticket is created / updated and the source code is available.

[Redmine official website](https://redmine.org/)